# How do I run X11 applications over ssh from a Gentoo server that does not have a GUI installed (with minimal added software)?

Tags: ssh, x11, gentoo

Currently I am renting a VPS from VPS.net running Gentoo. How can I run "X11" applications remotely without installing a full GUI on the VPS. What is the minimum pieces of "X11" I would have to install.

This server is intended to be used as a development server for graphical and non-graphical applications.

This is Gentoo I should be able to build the packages without the "extra" packages. I just need to know what would be required to get these applications to run on the server and use a remote "X11" server over ssh.

Comment: The problem with asking the "minimum pieces" is that the package manager will certainly pull many things you don't need if you ask it to install a GUI app. You might want to consider using things like sshfs (or the fish:// kio in KDE) to access the remote filesystem over ssh while at the same time using local applications.

Answer (score 1):

You'll run your things with `ssh -X` (assuming your laptop runs a Linux with some X11 desktop) and you would only install the packages of *client* applications, e.g.

```
echo net-misc/openssh X >> /etc/portage/package.use/net-misc
sudo  emerge -av openssh
```

this will pull the required client libraries, but not the server part.

You don't want any desktop on the remote VPS, only some *few* GUI applications.

Actually, for a VPS you really should learn more on the command line.

Comment: I do not have a problem using the terminal, I plan on using the VPS as a development server. This includes building and testing graphical applications.

Comment: Then perhaps you might want to install a desktop on your VPS. I am not sure it is reasonable.

Comment: gentoo uses portage not pacman